# How to use arbitrary `&mut` reference members and dynamic dispatch?

Tags: rust

Using `rustc 1.0.0-nightly (d3732a12e 2015-02-06 23:30:17 +0000)`, I would like to store a `&mut` to something within a struct and use it throughout the structs lifetime, making dynamic calls to it using dynamic dispatching.

The original idea was to store a `Writer` reference, which may either be stdout or an open file.

[This is](https://github.com/Byron/depot/blob/master/src/rust/hello/tests/lang.rs#L726) what I came up with, but without any success:

```
use std::old_io::Writer;
use std::old_io::stdio;

struct Container<'a> {
    w: &'a mut Writer
}

let mut stdout = stdio::stdout();
let c = Container { w: &mut stdout };

// now it should be possible to make calls, like 
c.w.write_u8(1);
```

The code fails due to lifetime issues, and I am unable to express that `w` is supposed to live as long as an instance of the `Container` type.
Also please note that I prefer not to use the heap, and thus boxed instances, for this, if at all possible.

**How would something like the above be achieved in Rust ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trait object, when stored in a struct, needs to know how long it may live for; the `'a` in `&'a mut` indicates how long the *reference* lasts for, but the lifetime of the object being borrowed must also be considered for reasons of memory safety. This is written `Writer + 'a` for an arbitrary `'a`, which can in this case be the same as the `'a` of the reference. The final incantation there is `&'a mut (Writer + 'a)`:

```
use std::old_io::Writer;
use std::old_io::stdio;

struct Container<'a> {
    w: &'a mut (Writer + 'a)
}

let mut stdout = stdio::stdout();
let c = Container { w: &mut stdout };

// now it should be possible to make calls, like 
c.w.write_u8(1);
```

Bear in mind as a possible alternative generics:

```
use std::old_io::Writer;
use std::old_io::stdio;

struct Container<'a, W: Writer + 'a> {
    w: &'a mut W
}

let mut stdout = stdio::stdout();
let c = Container { w: &mut stdout };

// now it should be possible to make calls, like 
c.w.write_u8(1);
```

Note how in just the same way the `'a` constraint on `W` is needed there.

Comment: Apparently I wasn't using parentheses around `Writer +'a` in one of my trials, thanks for clarifying the syntax ! The question is why Rust is unable to infer that.